# Restricting site access only to my router

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, ip

Trying to restrict my sites access only to one particular router, but the routers IPv4 address changes everyday, I want to allow access to my website only through my routers IP address how do I do it?

update from comment:

`110.227.***.***` is my current router ip address and `182.70.**.***`  is the ip address after I restart my router (Dynamic DNS changes any routers ip on restart)

Comment: post your sample code and what error you run into

Comment: i am trying to restrict via htaccess hardcoding the ip address of my router(externam ip address) but that ip changes everytime u restart the router

Comment: 110.227.***.*** is my current router ip address 182.70.**.*** and this is the ip address after i restart my router (Dynamic DNS changes any routers ip on restart)

Comment: @NahushRai 
As I'm also looking for a solution for this, have you solved this issue?